# ec2: Denied ssh permission / could not resolve hostname

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

I recently launched two instances, and can't get into one of them. They're in the same security group w/ same key.

Below are the logs and attempts for each server.[image]

Any tips / suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you launch both at the same time or separately? same AMI?

Comment: Different AMIs and launched separately in the console. On second look they were launched a week apart, though I don't know what that could affect... The most recent is successful, the old one (1 week) is the target.

Comment: It is possible you used different linux distribution for your target. Instead of `ec2-user`, can you try `ubuntu` in case you used Ubuntu. See: https://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username/

Comment: Its the default amazon ami for both. I tried ubuntu though, but still denied.